# Not able to see wifi interface in ifconfig in centOS 6.5

Tags: centos, wifi, networkmanager

I have added a wifi adapter to my CentOS 6.5 box but I am not able to see it in `ifconfig` output.

Wireless adapter in dmesg output

```
[root@testldap log]# dmesg | grep -i netgear
usb 1-1: Product: NETGEAR A6200 WiFi Adapter
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: NETGEAR
[root@testldap log]#
```

Linux version

```
[root@testldap log]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

nmcli output

```
[root@testldap log]# nmcli nm
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN
running         disconnected    enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled
[root@testldap log]#
```

ifconfig output (as you see no wifi interface)

```
[root@testldap log]# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:87:47:C2
          inet addr:10.22.156.151  Bcast:10.22.156.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:10:22:156:250:56ff:fe87:47c2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe87:47c2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1301 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2304693 (2.1 MiB)  TX bytes:340250 (332.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:960 (960.0 b)  TX bytes:960 (960.0 b)
```

drivers

```
[root@testldap log]# modprobe -l | grep -i wireless
kernel/drivers/char/pcmcia/ipwireless/ipwireless.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/wlcore.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wl12xx/wl12xx.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wl1251/wl1251.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wl1251/wl1251_sdio.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ipw2x00/ipw2100.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ipw2x00/ipw2200.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ipw2x00/libipw.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco_cs.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco_plx.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco_pci.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco_tmd.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco_nortel.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/spectrum_cs.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/airo.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/airo_cs.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/atmel.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/atmel_pci.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/atmel_cs.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/at76c50x-usb.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/hostap/hostap.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/hostap/hostap_cs.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/hostap/hostap_plx.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/hostap/hostap_pci.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43legacy/b43legacy.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/zd1211rw/zd1211rw.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8180/rtl8180.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/wl3501_cs.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rndis_wlan.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/zd1201.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas/libertas.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas/usb8xxx.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas/libertas_cs.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas/libertas_sdio.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas_tf/libertas_tf.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas_tf/libertas_tf_usb.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/adm8211.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mwl8k.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlegacy/iwlegacy.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlegacy/iwl4965.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlegacy/iwl3945.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00mmio.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00usb.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2400pci.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2500pci.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt61pci.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2500usb.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt73usb.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800usb.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/p54/p54common.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/p54/p54usb.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/p54/p54pci.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/ath5k.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_htc.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/carl9170/carl9170.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mac80211_hwsim.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmutil/brcmutil.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmsmac/brcmsmac.ko
kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
kernel/net/wireless/lib80211_crypt_wep.ko
kernel/net/wireless/lib80211_crypt_ccmp.ko
kernel/net/wireless/lib80211_crypt_tkip.ko
```

lsusb output

```
[root@testldap network-scripts]# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9050 NetGear, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
[root@testldap network-scripts]#
```

Could you please let me know what is missing here ?

Comment: added lsusb output as requested

Comment: There are 2 version for the Netgear th V1 with the `BCM43526` and there is no linux driver for it. The V2 with the `RTL8812AU`  [see Netgear A6200 v2](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Netgear_A6200_v2) . Use this git repo to build the driver : https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au